# SQL order by date not pulling after Feb 28th

Tags: php, sql, date, sql-order-by

I have a custom php/sql application that tracks inquires by day and displays the daily total for the past 31 days.

For some reason, the `ORDER BY date DESC` will not pull anything after Feb 28th. - Yes the date column is in the correct MySQL date type format. All inserted entries have the correct date, so I know it's not the data within the table.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT date, date_format(date, '%W, %M %e') AS day, COUNT('day') AS daycount 
FROM inquiries 
GROUP BY day 
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 31
```

I cant seem to figure out why the descending order shows that Feb 28th is the most recent day, when in fact it is March 3rd. If I go into phpmyadmin and order by the date column desc, it sorts exactly like expected with March 3rd at the top. Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `GROUP BY`? Does it work if you do just `SELECT * ..`?

Comment: Why do you need group by day here?

Comment: remove date from select and at group by repeat the columns declared at select, in this case: date_format(date, '%W, %M %e'), you don't need the alias of course

Comment: It will show the March entries if I remove the GROUP BY, however I'm needing it to show the number of entries per individual day on a single row. Why would the `GROUP BY` be eliminating anything after Feb 28??

Answer (score 0):

Simply changing `GROUP BY day` to `GROUP BY date` solved the problem...

No clue why it decided to break after Feb 28 though. I guess the `date_format(date, '%W, %M %e') AS day` gets messed up after a leap year day when sorting by the alias.

Would love to know why if anyone has any ideas. Thanks!